# Bootstrap 3 - Get Respective Element attached to Tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

With a series of HTML elements:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Element1"></div>
  <div class="Element2"></div>
  <div class="Element3"></div>
  <div class="Element4" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div class="Element5" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

A selection event reveals more elements, and this triggers a resizing of the main container:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Element3", function () {
  $(".Container").css("margin-top", "-42px");
  $(".Element4").show();
  $(".Element5").show();
});
```

Each of the Elements have a manual tooltip:

```
$(function() { $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() }); // activate tooltips
$(".Element1").tooltip({
  "animation" : false, // animation : false for dynamic title
  "trigger" : "manual"
});
$(".Element2").tooltip({
  "animation" : false, // animation : false for dynamic title
  "trigger" : "manual"
});
...
```

But the tooltips that are currently visible when this selection event (onClick) occurs, do not adjust their positioning to match the center y-axis of their respective Element.

Is there a way to get the respective Element of any visible tooltips, to iterate over and perform a `.tooltip("hide")` followed by a `.tooltip("show")` (as a way to refresh the tooltip position)?

```
$(".tooltip").each(function() {
  if ($(".tooltip").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).SOMETHINGtoGETatTheMatchingELEMENT.tooltip("hide");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).SOMETHINGtoGETatTheMatchingELEMENT.tooltip("show");
    }, 500);
  }
}); // adjust placement on movement
```